# Group columns and fit in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have the following data-frame:

```
structure(list(inst = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A8", 
"b7", "X1"), class = "factor"), steps = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("5", 
"10", "20"), class = "factor"), family = structure(c(6L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bay", 
"Grad", "none", "Upp", "base", "new", "tuna"
), class = "factor"), mean_error = c(5.930259, 6.0611, 6.241703, 
6.270109, 6.277435, 6.587473, 6.865757, 5.936106, 6.084044, 6.140153, 
6.142072, 6.146425, 6.364658, 6.621481, 6.759502, 7.02175, 7.16422, 
7.19518, 7.36932, 7.395606, 7.44191, 5.113961, 5.123312, 5.289946, 
5.292267, 5.455671, 5.768393, 5.840368, 5.140513, 5.346728, 5.371491, 
5.463127, 5.475944, 5.602034, 5.995647, 5.784786, 6.00454, 6.121524, 
6.22509, 6.24901, 6.37396, 6.41903, 4.0439, 4.223119, 4.260518, 
4.31062, 4.500065, 4.822419, 5.107085, 4.221596, 4.371242, 4.505292, 
4.524415, 4.681877, 4.703846, 5.14499, 4.944005, 5.007325, 5.0561975, 
5.1926225, 5.3353825, 5.34204, 5.63557)), row.names = c(64L, 
3L, 38L, 55L, 73L, 12L, 21L, 67L, 76L, 58L, 41L, 6L, 15L, 24L, 
27L, 70L, 44L, 9L, 18L, 79L, 61L, 63L, 54L, 37L, 2L, 72L, 11L, 
20L, 66L, 57L, 40L, 75L, 5L, 14L, 23L, 69L, 8L, 26L, 60L, 43L, 
17L, 78L, 62L, 36L, 1L, 53L, 71L, 10L, 19L, 65L, 39L, 4L, 56L, 
74L, 13L, 22L, 68L, 25L, 59L, 42L, 77L, 7L, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to create groups of three `steps` per `inst` in the x-axis and fit everything in one plot. The outcome should resemble this
[image]

So far I tried:

```
df_bri %>% select(steps, inst, family, mean_error) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x =  steps, y = mean_error, fill = mean_error)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

and I get this:

[image]

I don't know how to separate the groups into 3 `steps` per `inst`.

Comment: Updated the question so you can see what I tried so far @MrFlick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill=steps` is what you need:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = inst, y = mean_error, fill = steps)) +
        geom_boxplot()
```

[image]